# PHP -> PDO update if select returns less then 10 rows else insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Count before update / insert.

so simplified thats what i want to do :

```
if (select >= 10) { pdo -> Update } else { pdo -> insert }
```

**my idea was to use query :**

```
$select_today_usage = $DBcon->prepare("SELECT kood FROM koodid k WHERE STR_TO_DATE(kpv,'%d.%m.%Y')=current_date");
```

**and then check the row count :**

```
if ($count = $update_kood->rowCount()>=10) {//PDO update } else { //PDO insert }
```

But i cant access that count anyhow..

Comment: `rowCount` won't work with `select` use `count(*)`

Comment: You can mark that as answer, works like a charm

$select_count = $DBcon->query("SELECT kood FROM koodid k WHERE STR_TO_DATE(kpv,'%d.%m.%Y')=current_date and kasutatud=1")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($select_count)<=10) {

Comment: I've moved that to an answer, also added a bit to it because the above comment wasn't what I fully meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually meant to use the mysql `count()` function not PHP's. With your current approach you will select every record in your DB (which can result in high memory costs) I'd do:

```
SELECT count(*) as the_count 
FROM koodid k 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(kpv,'%d.%m.%Y')=current_date and kasutatud=1
```

then fetch that 1 row and access the `the_count` index.

```
$select_today_usage = $DBcon->prepare("SELECT kood FROM koodid k WHERE STR_TO_DATE(kpv,'%d.%m.%Y')=current_date");
$select_today_usage->execute();
$row = $select_today_usage->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row['the_count'] >= 10 ) {
     .....
```

For the longer answer, the PDO `rowcount()` doesn't work on `select` statements with `mysql`.

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

-http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php